# Call SetProcessAffinityMask in Java

Tags: java, winapi, process

I'm trying to bind a process to a specific core using SetProcessAffinityMask API:

```
BOOL WINAPI SetProcessAffinityMask(
  _In_  HANDLE hProcess,
  _In_  DWORD_PTR dwProcessAffinityMask
);
```

in C++ everything works fine but I'm not sure how to build the bit vector and call the function in java.

Does anybody has an usage Example of that API Method in Java?

Comment: How do you call the API function, do you use JNA or plain JNI or something else?

Comment: Yes, you are going to have to pick an interop framework. Show what you have got so far. Also, why would you want to do this? Generally it's a bad idea.

Comment: at the moment I'm using jna to call user32 and Kernel32 API functions  like GetWindowTextA, SendMessageA..., but as I couldn't find anything about SetProcessAffinityMask I have no idea how to use it in Java.

Comment: Well, you do it the exact same way that you call those functions, only the function is in kernel32. And it's very easy since the types are simple PODs. You might have to write the JNA wrapper. Where did you get the JNA wrappers for the user32 functions that you call.